# Function Definitions as Arguments

Tags: javascript

```
var cancel = setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(cancel);}, 500);

var cancel = setTimeout(clearTimeout(cancel), 500);
```

Scholastic question: The first of these two expressions work, while the second does not.  The setTimeout() method is accepting a function and a duration as its arguments and both of these examples are clearly providing that.  The only difference is that the first is a function definition while the second is a function invocation.

If functions designed to take a function as an argument can only handle function definitions, *how do you go about providing that function with the variables it may need?* For example:

```
stop = function(y){clearInterval(y)};
count = function(x){
    var t = 0,
    cancel = setInterval(function(){console.log(++t);},1000);
    setTimeout(stop(cancel),x);
};
count(5000);
```

The function above doesn't work because it's invoking the function

```
stop = function(){clearInterval(cancel)};
count = function(x){
    var t = 0,
    cancel = setInterval(function(){console.log(++t);},1000);
    setTimeout(stop,x);
};
count(5000);
```

The function above doesn't work because the stop() doesn't have access to the cancel variable.

Thank you in advance for attempting to educate me on the work-around for this type of issue.

Comment: You wrote the answer to your question as the first line of your post.

Comment: The first line of code isn't portable. If I ever intended to use the enclosed function again, I would need to completely rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The setTimeout() method is accepting a function and a duration as its
>   arguments and both of these examples are clearly providing that. The
>   only difference is that the first is a function definition while the
>   second is a function invocation.

Yes but when you invoke a function you return the result which could be a string, integer, etc..., so you are no longer passing a function pointer but some string, integer, ... which is not what the setTimeout function expects as first argument.

Think of the second example like this:

```
var result = clearTimeout(cancel); // result is now an integer
setTimeout(result, 500); // invalid because setTimeout expects a function pointer
```

> If functions designed to take a function as an argument can only
>   handle function definitions, how do you go about providing that
>   function with the variables it may need?

You could use closures:

```
var stop = function(y) { clearInterval(y); };
var count = function(x) {
    var t = 0,
    var cancel = setInterval(function() { console.log(++t); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { stop(cancel); }, x);
};
count(5000);
```

or simply:

```
var count = function(x) {
    var t = 0,
    var cancel = setInterval(function() { console.log(++t); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(cancel); }, x);
};
count(5000);
```

Comment: okay,  so basically in order to maintain the argument as a function, it can't be called (unless it returns another function).  The only way to place a predefined function as an argument is to wrap it in an anonymous function definition?

Comment: @Marlin, when you wrap a function call in an anonymous function you could basically preserve the variables defined in the parent context and basically *close over them* passing them to child functions.

Answer (score 1):

You get around it exactly as you have in the first line of code by wrapping the function call with an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the cancel variable to the anonymous function.

```
stop = function(cancel){clearInterval(cancel)};
count = function(x){
    var t = 0,
    cancel = setInterval(function(){console.log(++t);},1000);
    setTimeout(stop(cancel),x);
};
count(5000);
```

Comment: can't invoke the function within setTimeout()

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are always injected into nested scopes, for example those introduced by function declarations via `function () { }`. This is what is commonly called a *closure* and it forms an important tool in Javascript programming.

Therefore, `setTimeout( function() { stop(cancel); },x);` will do, the inner function has access to the `cancel` variable defined in the outer scope (it can even change its value).